# Why the "SIZEOF_HEADERS" in ld script is 0?

Tags: gnu, ld, elf, binutils

Below is some snippet from my ld script:

**Output format**:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386", "elf32-i386",
          "elf32-i386")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386)
```

**Memory layout**:

```
MEMORY
{
  CFLASH             (xri)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
  (...omitted...)
}

REGION_ALIAS("CODE",    CFLASH)
```

**Sections layout**:

```
SECTIONS
{
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", ORIGIN(CODE))); 
  . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", ORIGIN(CODE)) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;  <=== PLACE 1
  
  (...omitted...)

  .startup_bsp        :
  {
    KEEP (*(.startup_bsp))
    . = ALIGN (., 0x4);
  } >CODE =0xF4F4F4F4

  (...omitted...)
```

As I understand, the *location counter* "." stands for the `VMA`. At `PLACE 1`, the VMA should have been set to **0x20000000 + SIZEOF_HEADERS**.

But as I dumped the section headers from the generated ELF file, I see this:

[image]

**So the VMA and LMA are still 0x20000000, where is the SIZEOF_HEADERS??? I think it should be the ELF file header size but it seems to be 0. Why?**

According to [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Builtin-Functions.html#index-SIZEOF_005fHEADERS-588):

> SIZEOF_HEADERS
>
> Return the size in bytes of the output file's headers. This is information which appears at the start of the output file. You can use
> this number when setting the start address of the first section, if
> you choose, to facilitate paging.
>
> When producing an ELF output file, if the linker script uses the SIZEOF_HEADERS builtin function, the linker must compute the number of
> program headers before it has determined all the section addresses and
> sizes. If the linker later discovers that it needs additional program
> headers, it will report an error `not enough room for program
> headers'. To avoid this error, you must avoid using the SIZEOF_HEADERS
> function, or you must rework your linker script to avoid forcing the
> linker to use additional program headers, or you must define the
> program headers yourself using the PHDRS command (see PHDRS).

Answer (score 0):

So far, I guess it is the `>CODE` that ***overrides*** the VMA calculated from the location counter `.`. The `.startup_bsp` section is appended to the `CODE` memory region.

And since it is the first section for `CODE` region, it occupies the starting address of that region.